# Can't Switch to FullScreen Mode in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to make my SWF file run in a fullscreen mode. I was told to use the following command, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean: make the browser go to full screen, the answer is you cannot do it without the user giving permission to the browser.

Comment: I can't get it to switch to fullscreen even within Flash Professional. When I try to publish it as a webpage, the whole webpage is simply blank.